# why pixijs ignore this case?

Tags: canvas, raycasting, pixi.js

when I read pixijs source code, I found that the hit region detect algorithm that the class Polygon use is as follow :

```js
contains(x: number, y: number): boolean
{
    let inside = false;

    const length = this.points.length / 2;

    for (let i = 0, j = length - 1; i < length; j = i++)
    {
        const xi = this.points[i * 2];
        const yi = this.points[(i * 2) + 1];
        const xj = this.points[j * 2];
        const yj = this.points[(j * 2) + 1];
        const intersect = ((yi > y) !== (yj > y)) && (x < ((xj - xi) * ((y - yi) / (yj - yi))) + xi);

        if (intersect)
        {
            inside = !inside;
        }
    }

    return inside;
}
```

Obviously this is ray casting algorithm, but I found that this algorithm can't solve this case:
[image]

I would like to know why pixijs ignore this case